# How to Select Fields When Refreshing Model in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

As you probably know, we can use `refresh` method on a model instance in order to refresh it from the database.

Refresh completely reloads all columns from database. `refresh` method does not seem to take any input, so I was wondering if there is a way to refresh *some fields* from the database.

To demonstrate, let's have a pseudo-model as below:

```
Foo
---
bar: char
baz: char
```

And I have a single instance of `Foo` called `$foo`. `$foo->refresh()` fetches both `$foo->bar` and `$foo->baz`. How do I only fetch/refresh `bar` field?

Thanks in advance.

---

## Environment

- PHP 7.4.5
- Laravel 7.x

Comment: For which case you need to `refresh()`?

Comment: @MrEduar For [this case](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/32939). More specifically, Laravel does not seem to load `storedAs` columns because they are generated in database after they are inserted. Refreshing after MariaDB generates stored column does not kill for a couple of hundred insertions but what if there is more? It would double the queries which would slow down the performance twice as much. Selecting only one column for refreshing/freshing would be more performant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's no way to do such. The best option you have is to get the PK of your `$foo` object and query for the fields you want:

```php
$id = $foo->id;
$refreshed = Foo::select('bar')->where('id', '=', $id)->first();
$foo->bar = $refreshed->bar;
```

However, this will unsync your model with the database. Another option is to create a custom method in your model that does it in a more abstract way and retrieves the new unsynced object:

```php
// In your model:
public function refreshField(string $field)
{
    $this->$field = (new static())
        ->select($field)
        ->where($this->key(), '=', $this->{$this->key()})
        ->first()->$field;

    return $this;
}

// Then outside:
$foo = Foo::first();
// perform actions. . .
$foo->refreshField('bar');
```

Again, keep in mind that this will keep your model unsynced with the database. Also, this is a POC, I didn't test it, but the general idea should work. If you create a parent model and extend all your other models from this (which extends from Eloquent), this should work with any of your models.

For a more complete version, you can pass an array instead of a string and retrieve all the fields that you want to refresh, then assign them in a loop:

```php
public function refresFields(string ...$fields)
{
    $fields = $this->$field = (new static())
        ->select($fields)
        ->where($this->key(), '=', $this->{$this->key()})
        ->first();

    foreach ($fields as $field) {
        $this->$field = $field;
    }

    return $this;
}
```

I wouldn't recommend this, but if you really need it, give it a try. Good luck